# Cordova-open-native-settings open message settings for current app

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using [Cordova open native settings](https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings) to open the native settings.

Currently, I am using the following:

```
this.openNativeSettings.open("notification_id");
```

This does open my settings but it doesn't open the "message/notification" settings for the app that I am currently in.

I really want to guide my users to the right place, is there a way to guide them to those settings?

Comment: If this is an iOS only problem and works for Android, have a look at this issue: https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-open-native-settings/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the settings of your app with the [diagnostics plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) with

`cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToSettings()`

There should be the entry "notifications" which corresponds to your app